# How to add a number and letter - python (letter is also number)

Tags: user-interface, python-idle

```
        print("How old are you")

        c = input()

        d = 1
```

The question is - how to add d + c together

Or how to add 1 + c together

I'm only a beginner and I've been at this for hours it's really confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean c to be an input number ,then convert it to integer using `int(c)`

So you have `d + int(c)`

Comment: I don't get any answer doing it this way. It could be my mistake but I now have:

        print("How old are you")

        c = input()

        d = 1

        d + int(c)

Comment: You need to ``print()`` something in order to see output. Try printing ``d + int(c)``

Comment: Haha you're a legend you make it sound so simple. Thank you so much